# How do I add an icon to my Firefox Add-On with addon-SDK?

Tags: icons, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to add another icon to the Firefox addon I develop than the standard Icon:
[image]

I use the firefox-addon-sdk jetpack to develop it

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it to your `package.json`. That file is initially generated in your add-on's root directory the first time you run `cfx init`. This will add an icon (assuming the add-on's directory is "my-addon"):`

```
{
  "name": "my-addon",
  "title": "my-addon",
  "id": "jid1-1FERGV45e4f4f",
  "description": "a basic add-on",
  "icon": "icon.png",
  "icon64": "icon64.png",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "version": "0.1"
}
```

You can specify different icons for "icon" and "icon64"

> [here you see all possible options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json)