# How do I add more information to the info screen with firefox addon-sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Most add-ons have a lot of information, when you click on "more".

How can I add more info about my add-on visible for the user in his add-on overview?

I cannot find any of those options for package.json (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23854002/1069083)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the fields in package.json is here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json

The main field I think you're looking for is 'description'. You can put very long strings into that field, however keep in mind that JSON does not allow multi-line strings.

Comment: can you put such a long text with external links in it into that field?